# Detecting a unicode character (kanji) from a range of characters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I am trying to read input and pass it only if it is a Japanese kanji. That means the character falls somewhere between 4e00 and 9faf, according to http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml

Is it possible using Javascript to test over this range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/[\u4e00-\u9faf]+/` should do it. That matches one or more characters in the range `4e00 - 9faf`.

From the the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters):

> `\uhhhh` Matches the character with the code hhhh (four hexadecimal digits).

So in your case, if you want to test the whole string, you probably want:

```
if(/^[\u4e00-\u9faf]+$/.test(str)) {
    // str is a kanji
}
```

Comment: I've tried this exact code but the character I'm testing it with is not passing the test. Specifically 請.

Comment: `/^[\u4e00-\u9faf]+$/.test("請")` gives me `true`. Maybe you want to expression accept white spaces?

Comment: My mistake, I was forgetting to add .selectionText back on to the variable. Works now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to add that since asking this question I have learned that it's not necessary to use the raw unicode ID and you can just throw in the character itself. So for example, instead of [\u4e00-\u9faf] you can search over [一-龯]